# Javascript: take every nth Element of Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I get an Array with an unknown Number of data.
But I only have an predefined amount of data to be shown/store.
How can I take every nth Element of the initial Array and reduce it in JavaScript?

Eg.: I get an Array with size=10000, but are only able to show n=2k Elements.

I tried it like that:
delta= Math.round(10*n/size)/10 = 0.2 -> take every 5th Element of the initial Array.

```
for (i = 0; i < oldArr.length; i++) {
  arr[i] = oldArr[i].filter(function (value, index, ar) {
    if (index % delta != 0) return false;
    return true;
  });
}
```

With 0.2 it´s always 0, but with some other deltas (0.3) it is working.  Same for delta=0.4, i works, but every second Element is taken with that. What can I do to get this to work?

Comment: What is `n`? What is `k`? What is `delta`? What is `oldArr`?

Comment: How about `delta = size / n`?

Comment: 0.2 evenly divides all the integers, so `someInt % 0.2 == 0` always.  I think you want `someInt % (1 / 0.2)`, ie `someInt % 5`

Comment: @James `1 % 0.2` produces `0.19999999999999996` for me, because [floating point math is broken](http://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/1529630)

Comment: @Oriol you're right! `1 % 0.25` works (because 0.25 can be exactly represented in binary, I suppose), I guess using modulus operator on non-integer operands is a bad idea in JS.

Comment: Oriol, I wrote in my starting Post what those Variables are. @FelixKling, lol that sounds logical.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Maybe one solution :

*avoid filter because you don't want to loop over 10 000 elements !
just access them directly with a for loop !*

```js
 
var log = function(val){document.body.innerHTML+='<div></pre>'+val+'</pre></div>'} 

var oldArr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
var arr = [];

var maxVal = 5;

var delta = Math.floor( oldArr.length / maxVal );

// avoid filter because you don't want
// to loop over 10000 elements !
// just access them directly with a for loop !
//                                 |
//                                 V
for (i = 0; i < oldArr.length; i=i+delta) {
  arr.push(oldArr[i]);
}


log('delta : ' + delta + ' length = ' + oldArr.length) ;
log(arr);
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess that´s it. Especially since that should be faster than with the modulo-check. And I don´´t have 10k Elements. It´s an 2D-Array, so in the other Version there would even be 100k checks.

Answer (score 33):

Filter itself returns an array. If I'm understanding you correctly, you don't need that surrounding loop. So:

```
newArr = oldArr.filter(function(value, index, Arr) {
    return index % 3 == 0;
});
```

will set newArr to every third value in oldArr.

Answer (score 12):

Try

```
arr = oldArr.filter(function (value, index, ar) {
    return (index % ratio == 0);
} );
```

where `ratio` is 2 if you want `arr` to be 1/2 of `oldArr`, 3 if you want it to be 1/3 of `oldArr` and so on.

```
ratio = Math.ceil(oldArr.length / size); // size in the new `arr` size
```

You were calling `filter()` on each element of `oldAdd` inside a loop and you're supposed to call `filter()` on the whole array to get a new filtered array back.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Math.ceil()` to prevent the new array from being larger than the desired size?

Answer (score 1):

this also works by using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create the new array without iterating over all elements in the old array..

```js
// create array with 10k entries
const oldArr = [ ...Array( 10000 ) ].map( ( _el, i ) => i );
const max = 10;
const delta = Math.floor( oldArr.length / max );

const newArr = [ ...Array( max ) ].map( ( _el, i ) => (
  oldArr[ i * delta ]
) );

console.log( newArr );
```

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing from [@anonomyous0day's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33483558/1429980), generate a new `Array` with the desired indices from the given array:

(Take every `3` items)

```js
Array.prototype.take = function(n) {
  if (!Number(n) && n !== 0) {
    throw new TypeError(`Array.take requires passing in a number.  Passed in ${typeof n}`);
  } else if (n <= 0) {
    throw new RangeError(`Array.take requires a number greater than 0.  Passed in ${n}`);
  }

  const selectedIndicesLength = Math.floor(this.length / n);
  return [...Array(selectedIndicesLength)].map((item, index) => this[index * n + 1]);
};

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8].take(2); // => 2, 4, 6, 8
```

Answer (score 0):

may help!

```
 const myFunction = (a, n) => {

   let array = []


    for(i = n; i <= a.length; i += n){
      array.push(a[i-1]);

   }

  return array;

}
```